# Nginx RTMP playback only possible when started before / directly after publishing

Tags: video, nginx, ffmpeg, live, rtmp

I have an NGINX RTMP Server setup, unfortunately the playback of the rtmp source is only possible for a few seconds after the specific stream has been published.

Though connections that have already been opened e.g. Transcoding through FFMPEG works fine without any problems even for a few hours but they have to be started within a few seconds after the video signal is being published.

So while the stream is transcoded and hence definitely available, FFProbe can't find the specific stream ending with the following output (Debug mode):

[rtmp @ 0x7fadbdc0b5e0] Proto = rtmp, path = /live/4_9_lLV7GhFmTG0w, app = live, fname = 4_9_lLV7GhFmTG0w

[rtmp @ 0x7fadbdc0b5e0] Server bandwidth = 5000000

[rtmp @ 0x7fadbdc0b5e0] Client bandwidth = 5000000

[rtmp @ 0x7fadbdc0b5e0] New incoming chunk size = 4096

[rtmp @ 0x7fadbdc0b5e0] Creating stream...

[rtmp @ 0x7fadbdc0b5e0] Sending play command for '4_9_lLV7GhFmTG0w'

[rtmp @ 0x7fadbdc0b5e0] Deleting stream...

rtmp://***:80/live/4_9_lLV7GhFmTG0w: Input/output error

(Executing exactly the same command within two or three seconds after / before initial publishing of the video signal succeeds. Transcoding processes last for the whole duration of the stream) It seems that there is missing some header data that is used to identify the current stream after a few seconds.

Any suggestions on this? Thank you very much for your help in advance.

The Server configuration looks like this:

```
worker_processes  auto;
events {
   worker_connections  1024;
}
```

Server Conf.

```
chunk_size 4096; 
ping 30s;
```

Application conf.

```
application live {
        live on;

        access_log on;
        access_log /var/log/nginx.log;

        allow play all;
            exec_push /usr/local/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:80/$app/$name -async 1 -vsync -1
                        -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 256k -b:a 32k -vf "scale=480:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost:80/show/$name_low
                        -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 768k -b:a 96k -vf "scale=720:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost:80/show/$name_mid
                        -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 1024k -b:a 128k -vf "scale=960:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost:80/show/$name_high
                        -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 1920k -b:a 128k -vf "scale=1280:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -tune zerolatency -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://localhost:80/show/$name_hd720
                        -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:80/show/$name_src;

            recorder vod        {
                record all;
                record_path /efs/storage/vod;
                record_append on;
            }

            exec_record_done /usr/local/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -y -i $path -c copy -copyts /efs/storage/vod/$basename.mp4;
        }
```

As you can infer from the ffmpeg calls, there is one more application on this server (responsible for HLS delivery), though it should not affect this particular problem.

Nginx Server information:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3
built by gcc 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --add-module=/tmp/nginx-rtmp-module
```

Update: The problem seems to be gone when reducing the worker processes to 1.

Comment: Did you check the nginx log?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the nginx log does not provide any additional / abnormal data concerning this issue.

Comment: I have this issue too